# select from table by option into two different variables (php & mysql)

Tags: mysql

Im trying to select from a single table with two options and output to two different variables.

[image]

My old query was to calculate all deposits, and then run another one to calculate all withdrawals but this takes long time because there are many rows.

---

I want to get all amount of Deposits & get all amount of withdrawals in just one query (in php).

Example: SELECT SUM(amount) FROM transactions WHERE cId=10 ...help here...

output will be:

- Variable 1: 5500 (deposits)
- Variable 2: 2500 (withdrawals)

Comment: Sounds like you need to `select col1,col2 from table WHERE colx=1 and coly=2` In other words a pretty basic query. Of course if thats wrong, then you are going to have to explain your requirements more plain

Comment: I want to sum all user withdrawal and deposits in one query (in the end will be two columns - deposits amount & withdrawal amount)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM transactions WHERE cId=1 AND tStatus!='Withdrawal') AS deposits,
       (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM transactions WHERE cId=1 AND tStatus='Withdrawal') AS withdrawals
```

Final result:

[image]

Comment: See duplicate for a better solution